# View that only shows content that have a certain date?

Tags: 7, views, datetime

I have a view that I am using to list events, specifically "today's events." it was relatively easy to create it, say that I want it to sort by time, but what I am wondering, is how can I  filter it to only show events that are happening on the day that it is displaying. I am using the date module's CCK in order to create the date. I would assume that I would use the date start time, but I can't figure out how to filter that start date.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Filter by the start date with granularity of day.  When you setup the filter, you can specify operator `Is equal to` and in the Date default field use the keyword `now` to default to the current date at runtime.

Comment: What if I want to say "only display the view at all if there is no event `now`"?

Comment: Do you mean you want to display a message when the view is empty/returns no matches?

Comment: well I want to have two views. I want to have one that only displays "today's events", and if there are no events today, than I want to have a view that displays "upcoming events"

Comment: @Ephraim: I suggest you post this as a separate question so that others have a chance to respond to it and be recognized accordingly