# A view only shows if a certain filter criteria does not exist?

Tags: 7, views, datetime

I have a view that I am using to list events, specifically "today's events." I used a filter criteria to allow me to only display events that were happening "today" (as asked by an earlier [question](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/8617/view-that-only-shows-content-that-have-a-certain-date). I have recently realized that there will not necessarily be an event "Today", and if there isn't, I have a problem, because nothing is displaying. what I want is to have either a separate view (or do it in the current view if it is possible) that only displays if there are no events "today" what I want it to display instead is "upcoming events." that way, if there are no events on the day that you are looking at the site, than ou will see future events instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Under the advanced tab you can define "No Results Behavior".  This will allow you to add a view or html instead.  This will be in the same view.